# MongoDB: how to get the all the embedded data?

Tags: mongodb

```
 I have this data:

> db.Category.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542450a928db034349fb3bf2"),
    "name" : "A category",
    "products" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("542450a928db034349fb3bf3"),
            "name" : "Producto de categoria",
            "price" : 11.11
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run `db.Category.find( {}, {products:1} )` I get this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("542450a928db034349fb3bf2"), "products" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("542450a928db034349fb3bf3"), "name" : "Producto de categoria", "price" : 11.11 } ] }
```

I get the data about one product, but how can I get the data about ***all*** products?

Comment: Your example document only has 1 product. Not sure if I understand what you are looking to get back?

Comment: @JamesWahlin yes, but imagine I have more products, I want to fetch all them without giving a number, because I don't know exactly how many are there.

Answer (score 1):

If you had multiple documents containing products, you could retrieve all as follows by capturing the query cursor and iterating over the set:

```
replset:PRIMARY> var cur = db.Category.find( {}, {products:1} );
replset:PRIMARY> while (cur.hasNext()) {
... var doc = cur.next();
... printjson(doc);
... }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542450a928db034349fb3bf2"),
    "products" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("542450a928db034349fb3bf3"),
            "name" : "Producto de categoria",
            "price" : 11.11
        }
    ]
}
```

If you have multiple products within the "products" array then you would iterate over the array contained in each result document.

Answer (score 0):

Your NoSql statment seems correct. You have only one embbeded documnent of products that's why you got only one.

```
db.Category.find( {}, {products:1} )
```

Or you can use

```
db.Category.find({products:1})
```

Don't get confuse with "products:1", it is a projection that you want products. Here Projection is of type `{ field1: <boolean>, field2: <boolean> ... }`. Fields that you want to include explicitly in you querying data use like "products:1" otherwise for excluding use "products:0".

You can refer this link: [enter link description here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)